# Soma de itens ao alterar um registro

Tags: php, javascript, java, html5, ajax

Tenho 3 itens Acessórios, Pneus e Veículos, os valores são adicionados a uma tela de manutenção que é a principal. O problema é que quando é para alterar apenas um dos itens, o valor adicionado é apenas o que eu selecionei. Mas nao é atualizado com os outros valores

```
var TotalVeiculo; 
var TotalAcessorio;
var TotalPneu; 

function Somatorio(){
    TotalVeiculo = TotalVeiculo != undefined?TotalVeiculo:0;
    TotalAcessorio = TotalAcessorio != undefined?TotalAcessorio:0;
    TotalPneu = TotalPneu != undefined?TotalPneu:0;

    vmObjeto.selecionado.VlrTotalManutencao = (TotalVeiculo + TotalAcessorio + TotalPneu);
    $("#total").html("R$ " + vmObjeto.selecionado.VlrTotalManutencao + ",00");
}

function RetornoItemsa(aTela, aItens, pneu, total, quantia) {           
    var window = $(aTela).data("kendoWindow");
    window.close();

    ItensVeiculos =  aItens;
    TotalVeiculo = parseFloat(total);
    $("#btnItensVeiculos").html(" Ve&iacute;culos("+quantia+")");
    Somatorio();
};

function RetornoItemsb(aTela, aItens, pneu, total, quantia) {   
    var window = $(aTela).data("kendoWindow");
    window.close();
        ItensAcessoriosVeiculos =  aItens;
        TotalAcessorio = parseFloat(total);
        $("#btnItensAcessoriosVeiculos").html("Acess&oacute;rios ("+quantia+")");
        Somatorio();
};

function RetornoItemsc(aTela, aItens, pneu, total, quantia) {   
    var window = $(aTela).data("kendoWindow");
    window.close();

        ItensPneusVeiculos = aItens;
        TotalPneu = parseFloat(total);
        $("#btnItensPneusVeiculos").html("Pneus ("+quantia+")");
        Somatorio();
};
```

Comment: Está a faltar código na pergunta. Podes fazer um jsFiddle e [editar] a pergunta para juntar isso? Assim fica fácil ajudar.

Comment: Na verdade o meu problema esta nesta parte, os RetonosItem a, b, e c, vem de outra janela todos com parametros de total, que serão guardados na var VlrTotalManutenção. Ai eu digo que VlrTotalManutenção é igual ao total de todos os itens. Digamos que eu queira add apenas o item de acessório, os outros itens "Pneus e veículos" nao conseguem ser somados tbm. é como se os valores não c atualizacem.